# ASP.Net Free WebHosting to My Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-hosting

I have developed ASP.NET webpage using (C) and I have a domain too but now I don't know where I can find ASP.NET free (or 3 months free) webHosting provider for pushing my ASP.NET files and connect it with my domain.

I have tried a lot in google but all of them are providing free ASP.NET along with their own SQL Server.  But I don't want my data to be stored in someones server because all my ASP.NET forms are created by targeting my MS-SQL Server (which is available to connect via internet).

Is there anyone provides webhosting alone and let my webpages to store data in our MS-SQL server rather than saving it in service provider servers.

I have to show it with my organisation that the developed pages are working fine in web so based on that they will arrange local ASP.NET webhosting service for hosting our developed webpages.

Hope I made it clear.

Your suggestion/solutions will be highly helpful to me.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ASP.Net (Windows) web hosting providers offer ASP.Net with MS SQL Server databases, it does not mean that you have to host your MS SQL databases in their Shared SQL Server mandatorily. If your own MS SQL Server is configured for Remote Connections, you can host MS SQL database in your own Server and connect it to ASP.Net application hosted at some hosting provider. You just have to specify an IP address of SQL Server in connection string of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a student?

You can get Microsoft Azure access for free through their Dreamspark program.

https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99